# Algorithmic Identification / Engineering

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have a warehouse that receives orders during the day. These order can either be withdrawals or additions of products to the warehouse. At the end of the day you get an inventory list of items still contained in the warehouse. Because the workforce is stretched quite thin it can happen that an order is not taken care of at the same day it is received in the ticket system of the warehouse. Therefore at the end of the day you have to match the issued orders against the inventory list of the warehouse to find out which ones have actually been executed and which orders are still open.

Codewise i've been solving this by several nested loops just aggregating and comparing the inventory positions trying to match the orders. Unfortunately this is not really efficient and with a large number of orders and positions the resulting problem takes quite some time to complete.

In order to improve that i want to identify the underlying problem. I.e. is it Set Cover, Knapsack or something else and based on the problem and whether it is in P or NP is there an efficient algorithm or at least an efficient heuristic to solve it?

Comment: So You have some order records, but You don't know, which have been executed and which not. Every record contains information about warehouse item, including it's position in the warehouse. So at the end of the day, You need to learn which order records have been executed, based on the current inventory state. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: The records in the inventory list are simply the quantities remaining in the warehouse for each product, there is no position information. Apart from that it is indeed only the matching of the orders which have been executed.

Comment: Suppose you started the day with two A's and two B's, had 3 orders, one for an A, one for a B and one for and A and a B, and ended the day with an A and a B. How can you tell if the order for an A, and the order for a B were excuted, or if the order for the A and the B was executed?

Comment: I can't tell which of the orders was executed in this case, sine i lack further means of identification. In such a case i'd just go first come first serve.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, we know you have the following sources of information:

- an end-of day inventory list of items still contained in the warehouse
- "issued orders" which are to be matched against the inventory list above
- a "ticket system" about which nothing is known
- "orders" coming in during the day, but we've no idea if or how they're stored

One solution is to create hash sets from the current and previous days' inventory lists, then as you iterate "issued orders", compare the order quantity with the difference between the inventory sets.

The time for this is:

- the time to create two sets from unsorted (as far as we know) lists (if there's reason to care, the set for today can be kept for re-use tomorrow, halving this cost) - this is O(n) in the hash set size, and
- the time to iterate over the "issued orders" and do two O(1) look-ups in the inventory hash sets: that's O(n) where n is the number of orders

Sounds pretty fast to me.

Comment: This is to some degree what i'm already doing without the HashSets. I iterate over all orders and compare their quantities with the differences between the warehouse positions for each product type for each date for the last week. If i match a position i mark the order as executed.